# How to migrate from table without primary key using room?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to migrate to room, but the schema of my table was like this:

```
CREATE TABLE cache(key text, content text, time integer);
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "cache")
public class Cache{
    public Integer id;
    public String key;
    public String content;
    public Integer time;
}
```

No primary key was declared explicit, an error would occur while build:

`An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey`

I tried to add primary key to the table, but seems sqlite does not support that, anyone could help me?

Comment: Did you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from here: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-primary-key/

Unlike other database systems e.g., MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc., you cannot use the ALTER TABLE statement to add a primary key to an existing table.

To work around this, you need to:

- Set the foreign key check off
- Rename the table to another table name (old_table)
- Create a new table (table) with the exact structure of the table you have been renamed
- Copy data from the old_table to the table
- Turn on the
  foreign key check on

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code,you can add new column in your existing database  using a migration rules

Migration Rule

```
 static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
        @Override
        public void migrate(android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE cache ADD COLUMN id INTEGER primary KEY AUTOINCREMENT");
        }
    };
```

Add MigrationRule to Room database

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build();
```

New Entry class is

```
@Entity(tableName = "cache")
public class Cache{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public Integer id;
    public String key;
    public String content;
    public Integer time;
}
```

Don't forgot Room database version is `SQLite` db version+1

Comment: Not working. Got this exception:`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column (code 1): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE cache ADD COLUMN id INTEGER primary KEY AUTOINCREMENT`